# how to add random number to an array

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

This is classwork.  I've been reading and searching and everything is telling me to use the java.util.Random of which I understand how that works and wish I could use it.  but my assignment specifically tells me to use the (int) (Math.random * number) of which I am having difficulty seeing where to apply into my array.  everything I've seen has been the Random pulled from java. 
It is the generate 100 random integers 0-9 and how many times they occur. If someone can assist?
My error is - Exception in "main" java.lang.array index out of bounds exemption:10 and obviously there is something in my code wrong too.

```
public class NumberOfTimes{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    int[] counts = new int [10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){

      counts[i]++;
    }//end for

    System.out.println("number\t" + "occurence ");

    for (int num = 0; num < counts.length; num++){

      System.out.println(num + "\t" + counts[num]);
    }//end for

  }//end main

}//end NumberOfTimes
```

Comment: You've declared an array of length 10, and then you're trying to access elements up to index 99...

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Please rephrase your description of the problem in a more clear and organized way.

Comment: @HotLicks +1.  Also *"index out of bounds exemption"* please copy/paste the output rather than attempt to type it.

Comment: @HotLicks my apologies, in the section of my code that is 'count[i]I++' is I believe where one of my issues lies.  If I could use the Random then I would put it as '++code[1+ rand.nextInt(10)]'.  So I am trying to figure how to implement the math.random into the code.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you.  I am learning and all advice is appreciated.  I am using textpad and it displays onto the dos command which will not allow me to copy and paste.  Thank you also for showing me that I can tag my errors.  I was unaware of that and knowing is very helpful.

Comment: *"I am using textpad and it displays onto the dos command"*  I use TextPad (& Netbeans and Eclipse) & can copy from each.  For the command line, right click, 'mark', drag or arrow to select, 'enter' to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make this change

```
int[] counts = new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
    counts[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
}// end for
```

Comment: Yes!  thank you. It's almost always the simple solution that throws me.

Answer (score 0):

Your array can only hold 10 items, and on your loop you are accessing more than 10. Can be solved in two ways.

- Either Increase your array length

  ```
  int[] counts = new int [100];
  ```
- Or either decrease your count in for loop.

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  ```

Comment: I changed my code for the num to be <10 and worked like a charm.